# CSS doesn't connect to EJS file (Express)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I've been trying to include a my stylesheet file to an EJS one, and it doesn't work. When I tried doing it with an HTML file instead, it worked.
The CSS file is in the public folder of the app and I believe I've mentioned the public directory from which I'm serving the static files, as I've seen from other questions.

```
My app code:
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var about = require('./routes/about');
var login = require('./routes/login');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', index);
app.use('/about', about);
app.use('/login', login);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  app.use('/', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/web.html'));
  });
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The EJS file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%=title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/stylesheets/login.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<% include templates/header.ejs%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/login.js"></script>
</body>
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
            <button>create</button>
            <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
        </form>

        <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
            <button>login</button>
            <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

And the CSS one:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
    width: 360px;
    padding: 8% 0 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    outline: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: 0;
    background: #4CAF50;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
    transition: all 0.3 ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
    background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    color: #b3b3b3;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
    color: #4CAF50;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
    display: none;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.container .info {
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
    color: #EF3B3A;
}
/*Images was taken from Pexels.com, non-copyright website.*/
body {

    background-image: url("../images/bg-06.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: path you giving is correct?

Comment: yes, the path is correct.

Comment: tried removing the ../public to /public in href if the javscript path working

Comment: Try this link `/stylesheets/login.css` this line `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` serves all files in public directory so this file `<yourapp>/public/stylesheets/login.css` is served as `/stylesheets/login.css`

Comment: Molda, it has worked!! Thank you so much!!